# multiple list builder in flutter application

Tags: android, flutter, listview, dart, flutter-listview

I am able to successfully create a listview.builder in flutter application as per the below code.

CODE

```
Container(
     child:  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
     

    stream: query2.snapshots(),

          builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {


            var usernames = snapshot.data.docs.map((e) => e['itemName']);
            print("usernames");
            print(usernames);
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('Something went wrong');
            }

            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Text("Loading");
            }

            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index){

                // String itemname =snapshot.data.docs[index]['itemName'] ?? "";
                return ListTile(title:Text(snapshot.data.docs[index]['itemName'] ?? ""
                ),);
          });
        }
      ),
     )
```

But I want to have list view builder to be created on about 5 different if-else conditions which I am not able to do so, I tried to implement this thing on `StreamBuilder` but could not do it, though ternary operator works but for only two conditions at at time and not multiple conditions, how should I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is very simple.

```
if(condition1)
   return Container(color:Colors.blue);
else if(condition2)
   return Container(color:Colors.yellow);
else if(condition3)
   return Container(color:Colors.green);
else if(condition4)
   return Container(color:Colors.red);

...etc.

 else 
   return SizedBox();
```